# why is this not validating select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I want to validate my form that includes inputs, and one select , but at the moment when I want to validate does not  works with my select , how can I do it or edit my code to validate all together, but I am having problems with it . any ideas.

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var letters1=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var letters2 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
var email=  document.getElementById("email").value;
var password=  document.getElementById("password").value;
var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
var selectUser=document.getElementById("user");
var valid=selectUser.value=="select user";

if(email.length>0 && email.match(letters2))
{
    if(password.length>0)
    {
        if(fname.length>0&&fname.match(letters1))
        {
            if(lname.length>0&&lname.match(letters1))
            {
                if(selectUser.invalid)
                {
                    alert('please enter user');
                    selectUser.className='error';
                }
                else{
                selectUser.className='';
                }
            }
            else{
                alert("wrong last");
            }
        }
        else{
                alert("wrong first");
            }
    }
    else{   
                document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor="red";
                alert("wrong password");
            }
}
else{
                alert("wrong email");
            }

return !invalid;})
```

html

```
<select id="user" name="user">
                <option value="select user">select user</option>
                <option>Admin </option>
                <option> SuperAdmin</option>
                <option> Staff</option>
            </select>
            <div class="submitbtn">
            <a href="#submit1">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: ooh - a [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming))! Rather than the multiple level `if` statements you could break them down to their individual levels and assign the result from the logic tests to an error variable array. If that is empty after all tests then it is OK, otherwise bogus!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a variable with the name ‘valid’.
But you are not using it.

You should check ‘valid’ instead of ‘selectUser.invalid’.

Also the condition for ‘valid’ should be the opposite: The select’s value should not be ‘select user’

Comment: OKAY I WILL TRY THAT ..THANK YOU